# checking the URL has a protocol or not, if not then add

Tags: php

I have a form to get some urls from users.

**Eg:** web address, facebook address, twitter address etc. Then I need to check user may or may not enter the protocol as part of the address. If protocol is not with submitted url I need to add protocol to it.

In this case it is `http://`. As well as sometimes users may type the protocol incorrectly.

**Eg.** `htttp:/, http//, htp://` etc..

With this issue I need to know is there any way to remove the protocol completely which users has entered  and add new protocol with that URL to insert to the database.

I wrote some code to detect submitted URL has a protocol.. Its working little I am expecting but not 100%.

```
$url = 'www.example.com';
$checkProtocol = strpos($url, '://');

if (false === $checkProtocol ) {
    $url = 'http://' . $url;    
    echo 'This is new URL : ' . $url;
} else {
    echo 'Invalid';
}
```

Just assume $url have `htp://www.example.com` its become an invalid url.. not assigning the protocol.

Hope someone help me out.

Thank You.

Comment: So... if they've provided a protocol, it's invalid?

Comment: No.. Its ok. if it is a valid one like http://. but what happen they type incorrectly like htt://, htttp:/, htt:// etc..

Comment: Well then you need to check whether or not it's a valid protocol. I don't see that in your code.

Comment: my problem is it.. how I check it is valid or not and if its not valid I want to remove it and need add the protocol correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle all cases, you might just want to assume that the URL is missing the `http://` or has it malformed and just add it in all cases after cleaning the string:

```
$url = 'htp://www.example.com';
$fixed_url = 'http://' . preg_replace('#^.*://#', '', $url);
```

Comment: Oops, sorry I put the colon out of order in my pattern :)

Comment: if variable had something like this... 'htp:/www.example.com' then return invalid url..

Comment: if they forget to add colon... then? again invalid one

Comment: @TharangaNuwan At some point, you would need to determine what is and isn't acceptable as there is no way to distinguish where the intended resourcee identifier (http://) ends and the domain name begins (for example in `httpwww.domain.com/`). Personally I would only allow fully formed URL's (correct http(s)://) or domain names (i.e. no http(s)://) and not try to divine the end user's intent on a typo.

Comment: one thing can you kindly explain how this regex pattern work.. #^.*://#', '', $url

Comment: @TharangaNuwan Yes it is looking at the start of the string (`^`) for any number of characters (`.*`) followed by `://`.  You can obviously adjust the `://` part as needed to meet your criteria. I would suggest that you need to at least have a colon in there but may use `#^.*://?#` to look for `:/` and `://`.